# Is there a rails plugin to do effective dating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something like act_as_taggable or act_as_versioned but for SAP style effective dating?

Sorry for the lack of details. Here is some more:

The plugin would add a start_date and end_date to a model.

- Basic operation should always be on entity valid for today or a parameter date
- Update should make a copy of the effective entity with a start date of now and update the existing entity to set the end date now
- Delete should just set the end date to now on the existing entity
- Probably many more, but those cover the basic idea.

This is the way SAP handles versioning of entities. Does anyone knows of a plugin that does something similar?

Comment: What do you mean "effective dating"?

Comment: Versioning based on begin and end date so for a date x you can get a version that is effective. You can also have dates where no instance match so they can be considered deleted.

Comment: No, you've got to figure out your personal stuff on your own. :)

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean by "you've got to figure out your personal stuff on your own?" How is this question "personal?"

Comment: @jfno I'm not going to downvote, but it's a little frustrating when a question is just one sentence with no details, context, examples, or explanation of any kind. If you want people to take time to think about your problem and provide a thoughtful response it helps to meet us half way and put some effort into the question.

Comment: @Ethan Jeff was making a joke! "Effective dating" as in having a relationship with another human being.

Comment: Oh. Wow, went right by me. The emoticon should have tipped me off.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough problem. This means that every change you make to your tables take an "effective date" parameter. For example: Person X will be moving to a new address effective a month from now. So when you query the table today, you see the current address. If you were to query with an effective date of a month from now, you would see the new address.

And that goes for everything you enter in the app. Everything has a concept of when it became a fact. And you can see the values at any point in time, exactly as they were.

We are in the midst of finishing a rails project addressing this issue in an HR app. we will post something once this is completed.

Comment: Thank you, for this update. I'll be interested in any development.